# MYSQL Database connection to other website

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dns

How to connect **MYSQL Database** of `epizy.com` (which is free database provider), to `www.mydomain.co.in` (which is purchased domain)

Can we connect it!

Have a look what the error is showing [here](http://baidtransports.co.in/new/)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes I tried.. but it gave me an error

Comment: and the error said.....

Comment: The error says database not connected

Comment: and now? Should we start guessing what you tried; what you could have done wrong? Did you use correct function to connect? Did you use password? Is the database running? did you pay the bill? Provide SOME information about what you did and what the result of your actions were

Comment: it is working in the free domain but not in the purchased domain, and the database I am using is from free of cost...

Comment: Ok, then that sounds like a "cross-host" config, so does your user have permissions to access MySQL from the other host? If not, you WILL get an error. It would help to get the ACTUAL error message.

Comment: So how to access permission, we have to do from the configuration?

Comment: @PaulT. Please help me out

Comment: @BabaluPandey: If you are able to config the MySQL, as it says in the message (though I'm not so sure that the 'free' host will allow you to do so -- I can't make any adjustments to my free host, only to create/remove DBs, I have to login to their site), but there has to be a MySQL user account that also has the 'remote' host IP set to establish a remote connection. So, from your free site, there has to be a MySQL user table entry that has a user/pass/host (IP from the paid site) combination for the paid site to remotely access the DB. Does the paid site not offer MySQL?

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for your suggestions. Is there any other way it can be, because purchasing database in starting of the business, may lead to loss!

Comment: With `www.mydomain.co.in`, did you only buy a domain, or did you get a hosting plan?

Comment: I bought domain and hosting plan, but not database

Comment: You can't use their database from a remote server (you oftentimes can't do that in hosted environments even if you pay for it). You need to setup your homepage on their server. You can direct your domain to their servers, see e.g. [their faq](https://infinityfree.net/support/add-your-own-domain). Btw: Your hoster provides mysql for 0.83$/m. Btw 2: trying to save in the wrong place may lead to loss too (as the business might not start at all and you might spend more time (time=money/time you cannot do more important things/time for website load) trying to get it for free)

Comment: @BabaluPandey which hosting service you bought. Dedicated or Shared? Most of popular Shared hosting providers give you pre-installed services which includes MySQL. And if it is Dedicated one then you can install MySQL on it.

Comment: API integration maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain free database hosting provider which provides remote access to their database.

> Remote access here signifies all the requests made to the database are
>   originated from their own hosting server (eg, using their hosting
>   service for php, jsp etc) or any other hosting service provider.

But if remote access is not allowed means all request trying to connect database will be discarded if it's been made from other than their own servers.

So, irrespective of you correct ID and password to the database, you cannot connect to it remotely if blocked by the provider.

> 000webhost.com, comli.com are such providers for PHP based site
>   hosting, and, eatj.com is best for testing a Java hosted sites (but
>   for 11 days trial is only free) all above provider provides free
>   database hosting.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to have hosting first
- If your website hosted and working with database on the free host you have mentioned, then you can connect your domain by changing the DNS A records, you will have an IP address which you can browse your website through,  copy this IP address and then add it to the domain setting under A/AAAA Records in the DNS manager, after that you may need to wait up to 72 hours to see your website live on the new domain

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting to know exactly what is going wrong.

Or change `local host` to the websites SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You must have **IP** for free database provider then you can set this **IP** as your database **HOST**. 
Also the remote access must be allowed by the server if it is not allowed you can not access your database from different server. Please ask your server support to enable it.